# pip installed modules when packaging python scripts

Tags: python, pip, py2exe

I'm about to convert my python script into an executable with py2exe but I'm concerned that a few modules that I installed via pip (paramiko & xlrd) won't be included in that executable.  Does anyone know if those modules that are not from the standard library are included in the script when you move it over to .exe format?

Comment: Did you try it? Just run py2exe, temporarily rename paramiko in site-packages to _paramiko and see if it can find and use paramiko, then rename it back

Comment: ...  How did I not think of this?  Definitely checking now.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Artyer is right, and you can also check the exe file in another computer to make sure it's completely portable without additions

Comment: I actually tested it out, it looked like it was working so I just wanted to double check the files.  I dived a little bit into the build folders and paramiko is included in the source files if you import it.  Thanks again everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The paramiko folder - or any non-standard imported functionality - is located in the directory

> C:\path_to_your_script's_folder\script_folder\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7\paramiko

This folder holds all of the .pyc files that are associated to that imported file (in this case paramiko).

Thanks to @Artyer and @Ofer Sadan for their help!